# How to get the number of values in an option array?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using the jQuery UI widget factory, I have `options` that are arrays like this:

```
options: {      
  items: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
  cats: [calico, black, orange]
}
```

I need to get the number of values in these arrays later on to use in `for` loops. I have a private member function that has the option key as a parameter, and I want to do something like this:

```
foo: function(key) {
   for(var i=0; i < this.options.[key].length; i++) {
      //do things here
   }
}
```

The syntax seems to be incorrect, and I'm not sure how to get what I want. Using `.length()` causes an error that says `this.options.items.length` is not a function. I don't think it's a function, and I also don't think I understand how `length` is supposed to be used.

**How do I get the number of values in an `option` array?**

Comment: `this.options[key].length` or `this.options.items.length`/`this.options.cats.length`

Comment: length is not a function, it's a property, so just drop the parenthesis.

Comment: If you are using jQuery try a look to each() http://api.jquery.com/each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length` is property not a method, you are using it correctly. The problem is a redundant `.`:

```
for(var i=0; i < this.options[key].length; i++) {
                      // ---^
```

Comment: Why is the `.` redundant when you are indexing and not calling the option directly? ie `this.options[key].length` vs `this.options.[key].length`/`this.options.foo.length`?

Comment: @CaesiumFarmer Well, it's not a valid JavaScript, it throws an error, it should be `object[property]`, if you want to iterate through the properties you can use a `for ... in` loop. Or if you are using jQuery, you can use `$.each` utility function. `$.each(this.options[key], fn)`.